# How to connect to MongoDB in Kubernetes pod with Pymongo

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, kubectl

I wanna connect to a mongodb in a kubectl pod using pymongo.

I've tried this https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/01/running-mongodb-on-kubernetes-with-statefulsets/
but it just doesn't work.

I even used a post forwarding like:

```
kubectl port-forward [pod]-2 27017:27017
```

and tried to connect using localhost hostname (which works in mongodb tools like mongoshell) but it also gives me the same errors.

The errors I get are:

```
raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: [pod]-0.[service]:27017: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed,[pod]-1.[service]:27017: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed,[pod]-2.[service]:27017: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: xxxxxxxxx, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('[pod]-0.[service]', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('[pod]-0.[service]:27017: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')>, etc...]>
```

Notes [pod] and [services] are the pod and service names (but hidden) I'm using.

Do you have any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

I used the last version of python3, last version of pymongo and windows10.

Answer (score 0):

That article is very old. I'd recommend looking at MongoDB Community Kubernetes Operator: https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator.

Follow https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/blob/master/docs/install-upgrade.md to install;

Then https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/blob/master/docs/deploy-configure.md to deploy a cluster;

The instructions will show how to get a connection string (in the format `mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@example-mongodb-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local/admin?ssl=true`); use this connection string in your pymongo code.

Comment: Thanks! But what if my db doesn't have any credentials? How can I change this command:

`kubectl get secret <metadata.name>-<auth-db>-<username> -n <my-namespace> \ 
-o json | jq -r '.data | with_entries(.value |= @base64d)'`

Also I don't know the namespace, how can I find it?

Comment: The namespace is whichever namespace you installed the operator into. Try `kubectl get mongodbcommunity --all-namespaces`.